# Setting cookie in jsp response doesn't work at all

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

Can anyone please let me know why the following doesn't work ?

```
Cookie test = new Cookie("testcookie",value);
test.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365);
test.setPath("/");
test.setDomain("abc123.com");
response.addCookie(test);
```

I have tried in an alternative way to set cookie too.. Even this doesn't work.

`response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "testcookie = "+value);`

any idea on what would be the problem ?

Comment: How did you check whether cookie exists or not?

Comment: Browser - Cookies through Inspect element when the corresponding JSP gets loaded

Comment: Finally.. I got it.. The cookie was set when I added the same code in Servlet java instead of JSP